# Laravel controller to manage sent and received messages

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I write small inboxing app in **Laravel 5.5** for my wesite. In inbox app users can compose new message, read messages and delete messages. I have only one table in my database for inboxes.

#### Structure of messages table:

[image: id int(10), subject varchar(255), message text, from int(11), to int(11), created_at timestamp, updated_at timestamp, status int(11)]

And I have model Messages for this table.

#### Code: InboxController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;

class InboxController extends Controller
{
    ## Inbox View Control Methods ##

    // View for show new messages of current user

    public function messages()
    {
        $array = array
        (
            'messages'=>$this->user_messages('my_messages'), 
            'count'=>$this->count_messages()['my_messages'],
            'count_sended' => $this->count_messages()['sended_messages'],
        );

        return view('index', $array);
    }

    // View for show sended messages of current user

    public function sended()
    {
        $array = array
        (
            'messages'=>$this->user_messages('my_sended_messages'), 
            'count'=>$this->count_messages()['my_messages'],
            'count_sended' => $this->count_messages()['sended_messages'],
        );
        return view('sended', $array);
    }

    // View for show trashed messages of current user

    public function trashed()
    {
        $array = array
        (
            'messages'=>$this->user_messages('my_sended_messages'), 
            'count'=>$this->count_messages()['my_messages'],
            'count_sended' => $this->count_messages()['sended_messages'],
        );
        return view('sended', $array);
    }

    // View for compose and send new message

    public function compose(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isMethod('post'))
        {

            // Sended data from html form 
            $to      = $request->to;
            $from    = Auth::user()->id;
            $subject = $request->subject;
            $message = $request->message;

            // Get info about receiver user
            $receiver_user_id = User::where('email', $to)->first()->id;
            $receiver_user_type = User::where('id', $receiver_user_id)->first()->type;  


            // Get info about sender user 
            $sender_user_type = Auth::user()->type;

            // Send message
            Message::create(
                [
                    'subject'=>$subject, 
                    'message'=>$message, 
                    'from'=>$from, 
                    'to'=>$receiver_user_id
                ]
            );

        }

        $count = $this->count_messages()['my_messages'];
        $count_sended = $this->count_messages()['sended_messages'];

        $array = array
        ( 
            'count'   => $count,
            'count_sended' => $count_sended,
        );

        return view('compose', $array);
    }

    // View for read message

    public function message(Request $request, $id)
    {
        try 
        {
            $decrypted = decrypt($id);
        }

        catch (DecryptException $e) 
        {
            return redirect()->back();
        }


        $user_id    = Auth::user()->id;

        $messages   = Message::where('id', decrypt($id))->get();
        dump($messages);
        $message_to_id = $messages->first()->to;
        if($user_id == $message_to_id)
        {
            $subject = $messages->first()->subject;
            $message = $messages->first()->message;
            $status  = $messages->first()->status;
            $date    = $messages->first()->created_at;

            $sender_id = $messages->first()->from;
            $sender = User::where('id', $sender_id)->first()->name;
            $count = $this->count_messages()['my_messages'];
            $count_sended = $this->count_messages()['sended_messages'];

            $array = [
                        'subject' => $subject,
                        'message' => $message,
                        'date'    => $date,
                        'messages'=> $messages,
                        'sender'  => $sender,
                        'status'  => $status,
                        'count'   => $count,
                        'count'   => $count,
                        'count_sended' => $count_sended,
                     ];

            if($status == 0 && $sender_id !== $user_id)
            {
                Message::where('id', decrypt($id))->update(['status' => 1]);
            }

            return view('message', $array);
        }

        else return redirect()->back();

    }

    ## Helper functions for get any info from messages and users table ##

    public function count_messages()
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $my_messages = Message::where('to', $user_id)->where('status', 0)->count();
        $sended_messages = Message::where('from', $user_id)->count();
        $array = ['my_messages' => $my_messages, 'sended_messages' => $sended_messages];
        return $array;
    }

    public function user_messages($status = 'my_messages')
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        switch ($status) 
        {
            case 'my_messages':
                $messages = Message::where('to', $user_id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
                break;
            case 'my_sended_messages':
                $messages = Message::where('from', $user_id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
                break;
            default:
                $messages = false;
                break;
        }

        return $messages;
    }

}
```

How I can reduce code duplication and beautify my controller code?

Answer (score 1):

**Reduce Complexity, Follow SRP**
The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states that every module or class should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class. All its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility.

> Robert C. Martin expresses the principle as follows:
>           `A class should have only one reason to change.`

While this is primarily targeted at classes in object oriented languages it applies to functions and subroutines well.

The `public function message(Request $request, $id)` function could be broken up into at multiple functions, especially the contents of the `if($user_id == $message_to_id)` block.

The more separate functions there are the easier it is to understand or read the code. This also makes it easier for any programmer to maintain or debug the code.

**Don't Repeat Yourself**

In software engineering, [don't repeat yourself (DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is a principle of software development aimed at reducing repetition of software patterns, replacing them with abstractions; and several copies of the same data, using data normalization to avoid redundancy.

Generally when there is repeating code in a software module it indicates that a function should be written to contain that code or a loop should be written to perform the repetition.

When code repeats in different functions it becomes a maintenance problem. Someone can fix the code in one location and miss it in another location. The solution to this is to write a function for the code that repeats.

Answer (score 0):

- stop using SQL builders in your "controllers"
- stop rendering templates in your "controllers"
- stop repeating authentication in each class method
- stop using static function calls and relaying on global state

Though, I think all those are "laravel best practices" ... hmmm ... I wonder, what conclusions that might lead to.

Answer (score 0):

You can move all your business logic into services. I also recomend you to Use repository pattern in order to reduce number of queries. And finally use dependency injection || Service Container.

Here the link for [Service Container tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container). 
You can also create seperate class for handling your business logic and then inject them into controllers __constructor. Then you will endup with less than 10 lines of code.